# Object accessing the object that contains it in C++

Tags: c++, class, include, header-files, circular-dependency

I'm trying to create a game in C++.
It has a "Session" class that kind of manages everything. It contains things like a GraphicsManager, a SoundManager, and the current world. It also contains a static pointer to an instance of itself. This way, I want the world to be available for the GraphicsManager so it can be rendered, for example.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

main.ccp

```
#pragma once
#include "Session.h"

int main() {
    Session::getSession()->run(); //Starts a new session and runs it
    return 0;
}
```

Session.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GraphicsManager.h"
#include "World.h"

class Session; //Forward declaration so it can have a pointer to itself

class Session {
private:
    Session();
    static Session* s;
    World* w; //Pointer because no world is loaded at the beginning of the program
    GraphicsManager gm; //Required right away
public:
    ~Session();
    void run(); //Actually launches the game after preparation; not further declared in this example
    World* getWorld(); //Returns the pointer to the current world
    static Session* getSession();
}
```

Session.cpp

```
#include "Session.h"

Session::Session(): gm(GraphicsManager()) {}

Session* Session::getSession() { //Return an instance of Session. If no instance exist yet, create one.
    if(s == NULL) s = new Session();
    return s;
}

World* Session::getWorld() {return w;} //Returns a pointer to the current world
```

GraphicsManager.h

```
#pragma once;

class GraphicsManager {
private:
    void render();
public:
    void run(); //Calls the render method repeatedly; no further declaration in this example
}
```

GraphicsManager.cpp

```
#include "GraphicsManager.h"

void GraphicsManger::render() {
    World* w = Session::getSession()->getWorld(); //Get pointer to current world so it can be rendered
}
```

The render method is where I'm stuck. If I put `#include "Session.h"` into the `GraphicsManager.h` file, it gives me an error because apparently two header files cannot include each other. If I put a forward declaration at the beginning of `GraphicsManager.h` or `GraphicsManager.cpp`, Visual Studio tells me that incomplete types are not permitted.

This has been giving me a headache for weeks. I've made games in Java before and there this pattern was accepted. So how can I do this? If this structure is not possible in C++, do you have other suggestions for it?
[image: Scheme]

Comment: What is `GraphicsManager.cpp` including?

Comment: I am doing something very similar. What I did is set pointers to the "container" which contained pointers to all the other objects, like Graphics, Map, Player, etc. So each object could use the pointer to the container, and from there can access any other object via pointer.

Comment: frasnian: It includes its header file, of course. I forgot that.
Evan: Can you show me how you mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphicsManager.cpp, the compiler needs to know about the `Session`, so you have to `#include "Session.h"` which by the way includes GraphicsManager as well as World.

A forward definition will not be sufficient, as  the compiler would not be able to check types of `getSession()->getWorld()` expression.

Apparently your GraphicsManager.h doesn't rely itself on the other definitions, so there should'nt be an issue here.

Comment: This seems to solve the issue. However, the program still won't compile. The compiler doesn't seem to be happy with me using `s` in the `getSession()` function in the `Session.cpp` file. If I do just `return new Session();`, it works; however, this voids the purpose of my private constructor. Can you help me out there?

Comment: http://share.raptilic.us/2014-12-21_22-01-57.png
`error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external`
`error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol ""private: static class Session * Session::s" (? s@Session@@0PAV1@A)".`

Comment: I've tried to compile the code.  I get an error with `s==NULL`, because `NULL` is not defined.  Replace it with `nullptr`

Comment: Ah !  You have to add `Session*  Session::s;`  in Session.cpp.  All the static variables must be defined somewhere.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it makes sense. This thing is finally working now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try to include `Session.h` to `GraphicsManager.cpp`:

```
#include "Session.h"

void GraphicsManger::render() {
  World* w = Session::getSession()->getWorld(); //Get pointer to current world so it can be rendered
}
```

This way Session class defenition will be visible for compiler in `GraphicsManager.cpp`, so it will not generate incomplite type error. On the other hand, Session.h is not included to GraphicsManager header, so there will no problem that both headers include each other.

Comment: This seems pretty obvious and I have not tried it before. And it also seems to work.